# Как ввести, обработать и вывести двумерный массив с использованием функций и прототипа?

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Есть работающая программа, но у меня никак не получается добавить в неё функции. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int n, m, i, j, k, c, a[10][10];
    printf("Введите количество строк\n"); // начало ввода
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("Введите количество столбцов\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &m);
    printf("Введите массив\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            scanf_s("%d", &a[i][j]); // конец ввода
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) // начало обработки
        for (i = 1; i <= m - 1; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= m - i; j++)
            {
                if (a[k][j] < a[k][j + 1])
                {
                    c = a[k][j];
                    a[k][j] = a[k][j + 1];
                    a[k][j + 1] = c;
                }
            }
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
        for (i = 1; i <= m - 1; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= m - i; j++)
                if ((a[k][j] <= 0) && (a[k][j] > a[k][j + 1]))
                {
                    c = a[k][j];
                    a[k][j] = a[k][j + 1];
                    a[k][j + 1] = c;
                } // конец обработки
    printf("\nОтсортированный массив\n\n"); // начало вывода
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } // конец вывода
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Забыл сказать, что все переменные, включая массив, должны быть локальные.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Прототип_функции

Answer (score 0):

Вы это имели  в виду?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

// Прототипы функций
void input_data(int a[10][10], int *n, int *m);
void process_data(int a[10][10], int n, int m);
void print_result(int a[10][10], int n, int m);

// Главная функция программы
int main()
{

    int n, m, a[10][10];

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    input_data(a, &n, &m);
    process_data(a, n, m);
    print_result(a, n, m);

    return 0;
}

// Реализации прототипов

void input_data(int a[10][10], int *n, int *m) {
    int i,j,w;

    printf("Введите количество строк\n"); // начало ввода
    scanf("%d", &w);
    *n = w;
    printf("Введите количество столбцов\n");
    scanf("%d", &w);
    *m = w;
    printf("Введите массив\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= *n; i++)
        for (j = 1; j <= *m; j++)
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]); // конец ввода
}

void process_data(int a[10][10], int n, int m) {

    int c, k, i, j;

    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) // начало обработки
        for (i = 1; i <= m - 1; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= m - i; j++)
            {
                if (a[k][j] < a[k][j + 1])
                {
                    c = a[k][j];
                    a[k][j] = a[k][j + 1];
                    a[k][j + 1] = c;
                }
            }
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
        for (i = 1; i <= m - 1; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= m - i; j++)
                if ((a[k][j] <= 0) && (a[k][j] > a[k][j + 1]))
                {
                    c = a[k][j];
                    a[k][j] = a[k][j + 1];
                    a[k][j + 1] = c;
                } // конец обработки
}

void print_result(int a[10][10], int n, int m) {
    int i,j;

    printf("\nОтсортированный массив\n\n"); // начало вывода
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } // конец вывода
}
```

Только заменил виндовозные scanf_s на стандартные сишные scanf.